# How to get rows from two different SELECT statements with matching columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called relationships in my MySQL database which has the columns follower_id and followed_id. These represent followings on Instagram, for example if an account with ID 1 followed an account with ID 2 then a row would exist in my table where follower_id was 1 and followed_id was 2.

What I want to do is be able to find accounts that follow both account with ID 1 AND account with ID 4 for example. I have tried creating temporary tables using SELECT statements like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 
SELECT follower_id FROM relationships 
WHERE followed_id = '1'
```

and

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp2 
SELECT follower_id FROM relationships 
WHERE followed_id = '4'
```

and trying to cross reference the two temporary tables but this takes a very long time. Is there a quicker way to do this in MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT follower_id FROM relationships WHERE followed_id=1 AND follower_id IN 
(SELECT follower_id FROM relationships WHERE followed_id=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can select distinct follower_id using below query:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT follower_id FROM relationships 
WHERE followed_id IN ('1', '4');
```

Hope, this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple method is:

```
SELECT follower_id
FROM relationships 
WHERE followed_id IN (1, 4)
GROUP BY follower_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;  -- number of followed
```